# I need to find my bed in Minecraft 1.8

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was on my creative server and fell out of the world. I was in one of the little towns that are already spawned and I sort of built off of one of them, creating a larger "town". When I fell, I lost the place I was and I absolutely cannot find it. Is there a way to teleport back to your bed?

Comment: Have you tried a map?

Comment: did it say that your current bed is missing or obstructed?

Comment: If you died and didn't respawn at your bed, I think you're probably right out of luck.

Answer (score 1):

You can forcibly kill yourself with the /kill command.  If the bed is still where it was, and you've slept in it, you should be teleported back.

Answer (score 0):

You can suicide like the another person said but you could also use a compass that points in the direction of your current spawn point...

Comment: A compass points to the original spawn point (where you appeared when you first created the world), not your current spawn point.